# Typescript- show records only for todays date

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

simple question: How do I show a list of records that have todays date?
my HTML:

```html
<table class='table hovertable'>
        <tbody class="mytable">
          <tr *ngFor="let timeRecord of timeRecords">
            <th>
              {{timeRecord.date | date:'dd.\u00A0'}}{{timeRecord.date | date:'MMMM' | convertToSlovakMonthsPipe}}
            </th>
            <td>
              {{timeRecord.duration}}&nbsp;h
            </td>
            <td>
              {{timeRecord.allocation}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{timeRecord.comment}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and my typescript that gets all records:

```js
getTimeRecords() {
    this.timeRecordService.getTimeRecords()
      .subscribe(
        (time: ITimeRecord[]) => {
          this.timeRecords = time;
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: You can `.filter()` your array to only get the desired items.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.timeRecords = time.filter(t => t.getTime() == Date.now().getTime() );
```